# Windows forms: Metroframework looks different on Windows 7 and Windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

Problem occurs when opening Windows form in different OS (in my case: Windows 7 && Windows 10). I would like to know how to get it work on both OS.

[Windows 7 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caPgj.jpg)

[Windows 10 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zeBW.jpg)

Any solutions? Or I will need to make app in default Windows forms style?

Comment: The Windows 10 version looks actually like the Window would in Windows XP without designs and pre-XP versions. As if not a single modern design is applied. Do other windows in that Windows 10 look the same way? Because afaik, this is a Windows Wide setting.

Comment: MetroFramework has many unresolved problems and it's pretty much abandoned. Your layout  (at least what you're showing here) is quite simple to reproduce with the standard controls. If you need a control with a *special* look, you can always make one yourself.

Comment: Do you know any other "modern ui packs"? Any more modern ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! Problem was in **Windows scaling** (I had it at 125%).